# import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have eclipse and i have followed this [link](http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2014/07/04/how-to-setup-eclipse-for-android-wear-development):

but still the import "WatchViewStub" and "DismissOverlayView" cannot be resolved

Note ElizaChat sample wearable app is working for me .

so why WatchViewStub sample is not working ?

what's missing ?